# Is there a way to change multiple lines with one loop in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have a text file like this:

**info**

**:**

**I went to Paris**

**xxx**

**yyy**

**zzz**

**info**

**:**

**I went to Italy**

**aaa**

**bbb**

**ccc**

I want this text file to be like this

**Info : I went to Paris**

**xxx**

**yyy**

**zzz**

**Info : I went to Italy**

**aaa**

**bbb**

**ccc**

So it will be like;

1- finding every colons

2- (a way) double pressing to backspace button and moving to upper line and pressing spacebar + colon + spacebar + delete button which will get those paris and italy lines to the upper line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) for helping to simplify the regex and substitution.</sup>

```sh
# Outputs to the screen; pipe to Set-Content to save back to a file as needed.
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -replace '(?m)(?<=^info)(?:\r?\n){2}:(?:\r?\n){2}', ' : '
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/AvEubn/3).

Comment: You make it look so easy hehe, just learnt about non-capturing group that's great

Comment: Would it be bad to see it this way? https://regex101.com/r/Eg8DWl/1 opposite of what you're doing

Comment: Nicely done, @Santiago. Indeed, the explicit capture groups aren't necessary. I've tweaked your solution a bit and took the liberty of updating the answer with it.

Comment: The lookahead wasn't even needed lol have so much to learn, thanks for taking the time to answer that :)